# Create intentional kernel panic AIX

Tags: kernel, aix

Can anybody suggest a command or way to create an intentional kernal panic on AIX?
I did try echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger but the system call does not exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know is to start a system dump using

```
smitty dump_startp
```

or

```
sysdumpstart -p
```

IBM writes:
"Start the system dump using the sysdumpstart command. The sysdumpstart command starts a system dump on the default primary dump device. Use the -p flag to start a system dump to the primary dump device. Use the -s flag to start a system dump to the secondary dump device. Use the -t flag to specify a traditional system dump (-t traditional). You cannot force a firmware-assisted system dump if the traditional system dump is configured."

At least that's similar to a kernel panic and fully supported.